# C, trying to make a merging sort algorithm and i keep getting segmentation fault, not sure what i did wrong and how to fix it

Tags: arrays, c, mergesort

```
void mergeSort(int array[], int length);
void merge(int leftarray[], int rightarray[], int array[], int length);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    int unsorted[] = {9, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8, 7};
    int length = sizeof(unsorted) / sizeof(int);

    printf("unsorted array: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", unsorted[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    
    mergeSort(unsorted, length);
    printf("sorted array: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        
        printf("%d", unsorted[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void mergeSort(int array[], int length)
{
    
    
    if(length <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    int middle = length / 2;
    int leftarray[middle];
    int rightarray[length - middle];
    

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(i < middle)
        {
            leftarray[i] = array[i];
        }
        else
        {
            rightarray[j] = array[i];
            j++;
        }

    }
   
    mergeSort(leftarray, length);
    mergeSort(rightarray, length);
    merge(leftarray, rightarray, array, length);


}

void merge(int leftarray[], int rightarray[], int array[], int length)
{
    
    int leftSize = length / 2;
    int rightSize = length - leftSize;

    int a = 0; 
    int l = 0; 
    int r = 0; 

    while(l < leftSize && r < rightSize)
    {
        if (leftarray[l] < rightarray[r])
        {
            array[a] = leftarray[l];
            l++;
            a++;
        }
        else
        {
            array[a] = rightarray[r];
            r++;
            a++;
        }
    }

    while(l < leftSize)
    {
        array[a] = leftarray[l];
        l++;
        a++;
    }
    while(r < rightSize)
    {
        array[a] = rightarray[r];
        r++;
        a++;
    }
}
```

been at it for an hour trying to figure out how to fix the problem but no luck

Comment: You are overflowing with `leftarray[i] = array[i];` because you use the same index. You need a separate index, as you use for `rightarray[j] = array[i]; j++;` For example `leftarray[h] = array[i]; h++;`

Comment: @WeatherVane I disagree. `leftarray[i] = array[i];` is executed only when `i < middle` and `leftarray` has `middle` elements, so I don't think overflow will happen here.

Comment: @NawafBRQ  It seems the problem is using the value of the variable length in these calls   mergeSort(leftarray, length);
    mergeSort(rightarray, length); Instead you need to write  mergeSort(leftarray, length / 2 );
    mergeSort(rightarray, length - length / 2); or mergeSort(leftarray, middle);
    mergeSort(rightarray, length - middle);

Comment: @MikeCAT yes, and I just reached what Vlad already says. `mergeSort(leftarray, length); mergeSort(rightarray, length);` is incorrect, and should be `mergeSort(leftarray, middle); mergeSort(rightarray, length - middle);` i.e. the length of the defined arrays.

Comment: When you have segmentation faults, that's the time to use your debugger. You mention that you've been at it for an hour, to no avail. That hour could have been spent learning how to use the debugger. After examining the variable values at the point of crashing, you would have immediately realized that your loops are running off the end of the array. Another option is to compile with the address sanitizer, which should detect that kind of problem and report the line where it occurs.

Comment: In `mergeSort`, _two_ loops are faster (because there is no `if` in the loops) and fix the issue there with overrun: `int isrc = 0; for (int idst = 0; isrc < middle; ++isrc, ++idst) leftarray[idst] = array[isrc]; for (int idst = 0; isrc < length; ++isrc, ++idst) rightarray[idst] = array[isrc];`

Comment: @CraigEstey I'd expect any sensible compiler to generate two loops from that code anyway. But writing it with two loops is indisputably better in terms of being more concise and easier to read!

Comment: @paddy indeed, my first comment mistakenly thought an unsorted array was being split.

Answer (score 3):

This part of your `mergeSort` function is wrong:

```c
    mergeSort(leftarray, length);
    mergeSort(rightarray, length);
```

You are passing the same `length` as the input here, so this will become an infinite recursion (or runtime error *may* happen for out-of-range array access).

The part should be:

```c
    mergeSort(leftarray, middle);
    mergeSort(rightarray, length - middle);
```